Wi-Fi not working with Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 in Lubuntu 24.04 LTS
I am new to Linux and I encountered a problem with Wi-Fi not working in Lubuntu 24.04 LTS. My Wi-Fi adapter is a Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31).
Here are some system details:
OS: Lubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Host: 81FS Lenovo E41-25
Kernel: 6.8.0-51-generic
Uptime: 1 hour, 5 mins
Packages: 2039 (dpkg)
CPU: AMD PRO A4-4350B R4 2C+
GPU: AMD ATI Radeon R2/R3/R4
Memory: 1713MiB / 3378MiB

And here are the results after running the Wireless Info Script:

########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 24 Dec 2024 09:56 +0530 +0530

Booted last: 24 Dec 2024 00:00 +0530 +0530

Script from: 27 Aug 2024 10:55 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble

##### kernel ############################

Linux 6.8.0-51-generic #52-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Dec  5 13:09:44 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Lubuntu

##### lspci #############################

01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:38a6]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:0901]
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci, wl

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. Root Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:e500 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
Bus 001 Device 018: ID 22d9:276a OPPO Electronics Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f2:b581 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd EasyCamera
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 1a2c:2d23 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 105: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled
Platform is in Setup Mode

##### lsmod #############################

wl                   6488064  0
ath10k_pci             61440  0
ath10k_core           757760  1 ath10k_pci
ath                    40960  1 ath10k_core
mac80211             1720320  1 ath10k_core
cfg80211             1327104  4 wl,ath,mac80211,ath10k_core
libarc4                12288  1 mac80211
ideapad_laptop         61440  0
wmi_bmof               12288  0
sparse_keymap          12288  1 ideapad_laptop
platform_profile       12288  1 ideapad_laptop
video                  73728  2 amdgpu,ideapad_laptop
wmi                    28672  3 video,wmi_bmof,ideapad_laptop

##### dkms #############################

broadcom-sta/6.30.223.271, 6.8.0-51-generic, x86_64: installed

##### interfaces ########################

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp1s0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
10: enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.42.36/24 brd 192.168.42.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
       valid_lft 2173sec preferred_lft 2173sec
    inet6 fe80::ac03:34e7:7b1e:232c/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.

enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.42.129 dev enx<IF from MAC [IF2]> proto dhcp src 192.168.42.36 metric 100 
192.168.42.0/24 dev enx<IF from MAC [IF2]> proto kernel scope link src 192.168.42.36 metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root        1011       1  0 05:31 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/11
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         OPPO Electronics Corp.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        276a
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rndis_host
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 6.8.0-51-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               RNDIS device
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/net/enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:00:12.0-usb-0:1.1:1.0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 2
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       931a7056-8ca9-3b94-bfbe-e2ca4c411bfb
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/9
GENERAL.METERED:                        yes (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.42.36/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.42.129
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 192.168.42.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.42.129, mt = 100
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.42.255
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp_client_identifier = 01:<MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>' [IF2]>
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 3600
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        expiry = 1735016567
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        host_name = sakeen-81fs
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        ip_address = 192.168.42.36
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_nis_domain = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       routers = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::ac03:34e7:7b1e:232c/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 1024
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/12
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   931a7056-8ca9-3b94-bfbe-e2ca4c411bfb | Wired connection 2

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.TYPE:                           bt
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceBt
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         --
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        --
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         bluez
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 --
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E4_E2_6C_E6_0E_96
GENERAL.PATH:                           --
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
BLUETOOTH.CAPABILITIES:                 NAP
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/2
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   4f944e7f-a757-4348-b6ce-dacc5be25bbf | OPPO Reno11 Pro 5G Network

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp1s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 6.8.0-51-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp1s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.2/0000:01:00.0/net/enp1s0
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:01:00.0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-31-mac-addr-change]
match-device=driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### Netplan config ####################

grep: /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml: Permission denied
grep: /etc/netplan/90-NM-00453508-256b-3aab-8070-c51297943641.yaml: Permission denied
grep: /etc/netplan/90-NM-4f944e7f-a757-4348-b6ce-dacc5be25bbf.yaml: Permission denied

##### iw reg get ########################

'iw' is not installed (package "iw").

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp1s0    no frequency information.

enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp1s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[wl]
filename:       /lib/modules/6.8.0-51-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko.zst
license:        MIXED/Proprietary
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
name:           wl
vermagic:       6.8.0-51-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           passivemode:int
parm:           wl_txq_thresh:int
parm:           oneonly:int
parm:           piomode:int
parm:           instance_base:int
parm:           nompc:int
parm:           intf_name:string

[ath10k_pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/6.8.0-51-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_pci.ko.zst
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Driver support for Qualcomm Atheros PCIe/AHB 802.11ac WLAN devices
depends:        ath10k_core
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ath10k_pci
vermagic:       6.8.0-51-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           irq_mode:0: auto, 1: legacy, 2: msi (default: 0) (uint)
parm:           reset_mode:0: auto, 1: warm only (default: 0) (uint)

[ath10k_core]
filename:       /lib/modules/6.8.0-51-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_core.ko.zst
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Core module for Qualcomm Atheros 802.11ac wireless LAN cards.
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211,ath
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ath10k_core
vermagic:       6.8.0-51-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           debug_mask:Debugging mask (uint)
parm:           uart_print:Uart target debugging (bool)
parm:           skip_otp:Skip otp failure for calibration in testmode (bool)
parm:           cryptmode:Crypto mode: 0-hardware, 1-software (uint)
parm:           frame_mode:Datapath frame mode (0: raw, 1: native wifi (default), 2: ethernet) (uint)
parm:           coredump_mask:Bitfield of what to include in firmware crash file (ulong)
parm:           fw_diag_log:Diag based fw log debugging (bool)

[ath]
filename:       /lib/modules/6.8.0-51-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko.zst
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless LAN cards.
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ath
vermagic:       6.8.0-51-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/6.8.0-51-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko.zst
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
depends:        cfg80211,libarc4
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       6.8.0-51-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/6.8.0-51-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko.zst
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       6.8.0-51-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[ath10k_pci]
irq_mode: 0
reset_mode: 0

[ath10k_core]
coredump_mask: 3
cryptmode: 0
debug_mask: 0
frame_mode: 1
fw_diag_log: N
skip_otp: N
uart_print: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-sta-dkms.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist b44
blacklist bcma
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist ssb

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

########## wireless info END ############


idk how can i tell you than?

OS: Lubuntu 24.04.1 LTS x86

I am losing my mind... how cn i help you provide the stuff you ask i am new gosh

Nothing working

Please see https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos  run the wireless script and press y when asked to upload results, post URL from terminal here

It give me a link after executing the code in terminal: https://termbin.com/rf9j

Anything happen with sudo modprobe -v ath10k_pci and also do sudo apt remove broadcom-sta broadcom-sta-dkms

Okay i will try it when i am in home?

will that is the only problem?

I already ready to change my Os to windows though and througght windows i will switich to "Pop Os!"

It could be that power management is causing the driver to crash

YEAH YOU COULD BE RIGHT CUZ IT SHOCKS AT SOME PLACES OF LAPTOP

Any result from terminal for sudo dmesg | grep ath

I got a Wifi dongle... Thank you for your support, Sir.
